Nvidia GPU doesn't work on any distribution
My laptop had always had some issues related to the NVidia dGPU the NVidia RTX A500.
Basically, I tried plenty different distributions, they all had either artefacts, or freezes, or both. Except for Fedora 40, which is now old.
So I searched around a bit and realised that it is supposed to be supported by Ubuntu:

My Laptop - Lenovo ThinkPad P16v Gen 1 (AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 7840HS, NVIDIA RTX A500)

So I installed Ubuntu LTS 24.04 and the nvidia drivers it proposed, but I still have artefacts. Note that the glitches appear a lot after booting, then after 5 min they calm down a bit. In the link, it is written that it is some kind of special ISO.

Is there a way I could acquire it, and does it make a big difference?
Also, does anyone know how I could solve this issue?


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This laptop is also supported in Gentoo.  See: Lenovo ThinkPad P16v 1st Generation (AMD). This may help with driver selection. See column Kernel Drivers

@eyoung100 that's not exactly the same laptop. Different processor and different GPU.

When I googled by AMD device ID: 1002:15bf 17aa:231d, that link came up and as a Gentoo user I can confirm our users are accurate.  The 15bf is in the same family, which means its the same driver.  Copy the device ID paste it in google then it's the 2nd link from the top

Your laptop is using a form of vga_switcharoo.  It used to be NVIDA/Intel and AMD/Intel but Lenovo got fancy and Mixed both now.  See NVIDIA Optimus. Get the AMD card working without the NVIDIA drivers as that drives X and then turn the discrete NVIDIA card.

You may want to try official Nvidia drivers, available for your card here. Download option gets and installation script that you should run.
I advice to read the script first, or at least run it with the --help parameter.
